# Multiple graphs with same x-axis in Google Charts

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, google-visualization

I want to use multiple line charts/annotated timeline charts using same x-axis and separate Y-axis.

The way Google finance does it.
http://www.google.com/finance?q=NASDAQ:GOOG

When the x-axis is scrolled, both the graphs move.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What will you be using the create the graph?

Comment: I will use my own data series. The goal is to get multiple dataseries with different scales. If you look at the google finance graphs - It has three types of data-series 1. actual stock value 2. Volume 3. BIAS

Answer (score 0):

I do not think the particular chart which you have cited as an example is implemented using Google Chart Api. For that I think you might have to use a third party component such as FusionCharts.

Comment: Google finance graphs are drawn using Google charts, mostly the problem is Google hasn't exposed all of their APIs.